# React onchange event: this.setState() not setting state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onchange

I am trying to set state via `this.setState()` of username and password when user types a value in username and password field. I am using `onChange` event type

> **ISSUE**: the state is not changing. I log this.state.data.username in the render().

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

var Joi = require("joi-browser");

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    data: { username: "a", password: "b " },
    errors: {
      email: "ddsfds",
      password: "aaaa"
    }
  };

  schema = {
    username: Joi.string()
      .min(0)
      .required()
      .label("Username"),
    password: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Password")
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submited.", event.target);

    const { data } = this.state;

    const { err } = Joi.validate(data, this.schema);

    if (err) {
      console.log("error is true", err);
    } else {
      console.log("not true");
    }
  };

  handleEmailOnChange = event => {
    const inputUsername = event.target.value;
    console.log("input is...", inputUsername);

    this.setState({ username: inputUsername });
  };

  handlePassword = event => {
    const passwordInput = event.target.value;

    this.setState({ password: passwordInput });
  };

  render() {
    console.log("username ", this.state.data.username);
    return (
      <div id="form-wrapper">
        <Form>
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <h4>Sign In</h4>
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter email"
              onChange={this.handleEmailOnChange}
            />
            {/* <span>{this.state.errors.username} </span> */}
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={this.handlePassword}
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <div id="register-wrapper">
            <Link to="/register" type="button" className="btn btn-warning">
              Register Account
            </Link>
            <Button
              variant="primary"
              className="m-2"
              type="submit"
              onClick={this.handleSubmit}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: The state you are changing is `this.state.username`, the one you console is `this.state.data.username`

Comment: this.setState({ username: inputUsername }); <--- here? How to i select this.state.data.username... not sure?

Comment: Atm  this is what i have (ugly): 
    const { username } = this.state.data;

    let a = username;

    this.setState({ a: inputUsername });

Comment: @Shaz, even if you destructure the value, while setting state you need to specify the complete nested structure rather than just the nested key. Please check the answers below on how to do that

Comment: Ah! So If i have nested state object properties, I have to use prevState ... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't updating the state correctly or not using it correctly. The state in your constructor has data object with `username` and `password`

```
 handleEmailOnChange = event => {
    const inputUsername = event.target.value;
    console.log("input is...", inputUsername);

    this.setState(prev => ({data: {...prev.data, username: inputUsername } }));
  };

  handlePassword = event => {
    const passwordInput = event.target.value;
    this.setState(prev => ({data: {...prev.data, password: passwordInput } }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The state you are changing is `this.state.username`, the one you console is `this.state.data.username`.

To set `data` in your state, use:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: {
    username: inputUsername,
    ...prevState.data
  }
})
```